# Is it Possible to create a desktop shortcut for the Sage Notebook?

Tags: 12.10, 32-bit, sagemath

**Sage** is a python-based mathematics software that integrates a wide range of mathematics software into a single python interface.

Calling **sage** from the terminal (which is how you call it) creates a **CLI** version of sage (the program's default) from which you can then call the sage notebook by typing, `notebook()`. The **sage notebook** is a web browser-based version of sage. I am running i386 12.10 if it helps.

When I run `sage notebook()` from the terminal I receive the error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: What happens if you run `sage notebook()` as one command?

Comment: I have edited it into my question.

Comment: How about `sage "notebook()"`?

Comment: python: can't open file 'notebook()': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I believe that `sage -n` or `sage -notebook` will be the correct terminal command.

Comment: @JaakkoSeppälä If you write that up as an answer I will accept it. Otherwise in 1 week I will write it up myself and accept said answer so  I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a shortcut that runs the command `sage -n` or `sage -notebook`.

Comment: And why is that a desktop shortcut?

Comment: Well, it is not a shortcut. I edited the answer.